Which animes have an "official day" in Japan?
According to this, and several other articles in social networks,
One Piece Official Day

Japan officialy declared July 22 as One Piece Day

Which animes have an "official day" in Japan?

Idk what level of 'official' you are thinking, but in case of One Piece, it's most probably a matter of marketing. Around this time of the year, summer vacation for primary/secondary school kids starts, and I'm guessing the day is fixed so that it coincides.

There are animes that have associated dates, like September 3rd for Doraemon (the day of Doraemon's creation/birthday).

@sundowner official like the govenment of Japan declared it

Japanese gov has nothing to do with it. According to here, the publisher submitted the "anniversary" themselves to the organization.

@sundowner I guess there are several posts in social networks lying then. Which it wouldnt be a surprise
